# What is the security impact of not generating a unique key for each application?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, security, load-balancing

I have Server 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5 web servers behind a hardware load balancer. In order to get load balancing working, I had to specify a common IIS machine key between the servers, and disable the option to "generate a unique key for each application" for the validation and the decryption keys (also use a session state server, but that doesn't matter now).

The Machine Key section of the IIS GUI says "to increase security among applications, generate a unique key for each application." What is the security risk if I don't "generate a unique key for each application"?

Answer (score 0):

If key of one machine is compromised, it means that attacker can use the same key to decrypt communications from other machines sharing the key. Think of risk as you sharing the password with multiple people.

The attacker will also be able to predict session IDs or create ones that are compatible with your other server(s).

Comment: I understand that about common machine keys - it's necessary for a web farm scenario, but I'm asking about unique keys for each application.